# What's the type of a catamorphism (fold) for non-regular recursive types?

Tags: haskell, types, catamorphism, recursion-schemes

Many catamorphisms seem to be simple enough, mostly replacing each data constructor with a custom function, e.g.

```
data Bool = False | True
foldBool :: r              -- False constructor
         -> r              -- True constructor
         -> Bool -> r

data Maybe a = Nothing | Just a
foldMaybe :: b             -- Nothing constructor
          -> (a -> b)      -- Just constructor
          -> Maybe a -> b

data List a = Empty | Cons a (List a)
foldList :: b              -- Empty constructor
         -> (a -> b -> b)  -- Cons constructor
         -> List a -> b
```

However, what's not clear to me is what happens if the same type constructor is used, but with a different type argument. E.g. instead of passing a `List a` to `Cons`, what about

```
data List a = Empty | Cons a (List (a,a))
```

Or, maybe a more crazy case:

```
data List a = Empty | Cons a (List (List a))
foldList :: b              -- Empty constructor
         -> ???            -- Cons constructor
         -> List a -> b
```

The two plausible ideas I have for the `???` part are

- `(a -> b -> b)`, i.e. replacing all applications of the `List` constructor recursively)
- `(a -> List b -> b)`, i.e. merely replacing all `List a` applications.

Which of the two would be correct - and why? Or would it be something different altogether?

Comment: Polymorphic recursion is definitely nontrivial. A less extreme example than yours you might want to add as an intermediate step is `data List a = Empty | Cons a (List (a,a))`.

Comment: @chi Thanks! I think `non-regular recursive types` are a term I should have mentioned - I adjusted the title of my question - I never liked the `this type` part. I also incorporated your less extreme example into my question.

Comment: In my understanding folds are defined only for those recursive data types that arise as initial algebra for an endofunctor F. I doubt that every recursive data types is of this form and so that every data type should have a fold....anyway I'm not sure whether your data type admit a fold.

Comment: [this 2007 haskell-cafe message](https://mail.haskell.org/pipermail/haskell-cafe/2007-March/023405.html) seems relevant.

Answer (score 5):

This is a partial answer, only.

The issue the OP raises is: how to define `fold`/`cata` in the case of non-regular recursive types?

Since I don't trust myself in getting this right, I will resort to asking Coq instead. Let's start from a simple, regular recursive list type.

```
Inductive List (A : Type) : Type :=
  | Empty: List A
  | Cons : A -> List A -> List A
.
```

Nothing fancy here, `List A` is defined in terms of `List A`.
(Remember this -- we'll get back to it.)

What about the `cata`? Let's query the induction pinciple.

```
> Check List_rect.
forall (A : Type) (P : List A -> Type),
   P (Empty A) ->
   (forall (a : A) (l : List A), P l -> P (Cons A a l)) ->
   forall l : List A, P l
```

Let's see. The above exploits dependent types: `P` depends on the actual value of the list. Let's just manually simplify it in the case `P list` is a constant type `B`. We obtain:

```
forall (A : Type) (B : Type),
   B ->
   (forall (a : A) (l : List A), B -> B) ->
   forall l : List A, B
```

which can be equivalently written as

```
forall (A : Type) (B : Type),
   B ->
   (A -> List A -> B -> B) ->
   List A -> B
```

Which is `foldr` except that the "current list" is also passed to the binary function argument -- not a major difference.

Now, in Coq we can define a list in another subtly different way:

```
Inductive List2 : Type -> Type :=
  | Empty2: forall A, List2 A
  | Cons2 : forall A, A -> List2 A -> List2 A
.
```

It looks the same type, but there is a profound difference. Here we are not defining the type `List A` in terms of `List A`. Rather, we are defining a type function `List2 : Type -> Type` in terms of `List2`. The main point of this is that the recursive references to `List2` do not have to be applied to `A` -- the fact that above we do so is only an incident.

Anyway, let's see the type for the induction principle:

```
> Check List2_rect.
forall P : forall T : Type, List2 T -> Type,
   (forall A : Type, P A (Empty2 A)) ->
   (forall (A : Type) (a : A) (l : List2 A), P A l -> P A (Cons2 A a l)) ->
   forall (T : Type) (l : List2 T), P T l
```

Let's remove the `List2 T` argument from `P` as we did before, basically assuming `P` is constant on it.

```
forall P : forall T : Type, Type,
   (forall A : Type, P A ) ->
   (forall (A : Type) (a : A) (l : List2 A), P A -> P A) ->
   forall (T : Type) (l : List2 T), P T
```

Equivalently rewritten:

```
forall P : (Type -> Type),
   (forall A : Type, P A) ->
   (forall (A : Type), A -> List2 A -> P A -> P A) ->
   forall (T : Type), List2 T -> P T
```

Which roughly corresponds, in Haskell notation

```
(forall a, p a) ->                          -- Empty
(forall a, a -> List2 a -> p a -> p a) ->   -- Cons
List2 t -> p t
```

Not so bad -- the base case now has to be a polymorphic function, much as `Empty` in Haskell is. It makes some sense. Similarly, the inductive case must be a polymorphic function, much as `Cons` is. There's an extra `List2 a` argument, but we can ignore that, if we want.

Now, the above is still a kind of fold/cata on a *regular* type. What about non regular ones? I will study

```
data List a = Empty | Cons a (List (a,a))
```

which in Coq becomes:

```
Inductive  List3 : Type -> Type :=
  | Empty3: forall A, List3 A
  | Cons3 : forall A, A -> List3 (A * A) -> List3 A
.
```

with induction principle:

```
> Check List3_rect.
forall P : forall T : Type, List3 T -> Type,
   (forall A : Type, P A (Empty3 A)) ->
   (forall (A : Type) (a : A) (l : List3 (A * A)), P (A * A) l -> P A (Cons3 A a l)) ->
   forall (T : Type) (l : List3 T), P T l
```

Removing the "dependent" part:

```
forall P : (Type -> Type),
   (forall A : Type, P A) ->
   (forall (A : Type), A -> List3 (A * A) -> P (A * A) -> P A ) ->
   forall (T : Type), List3 T -> P T
```

In Haskell notation:

```
   (forall a. p a) ->                                      -- empty
   (forall a, a -> List3 (a, a) -> p (a, a) -> p a ) ->    -- cons
   List3 t -> p t
```

Aside from the additional `List3 (a, a)` argument, this is a kind of fold.

Finally, what about the OP type?

```
data List a = Empty | Cons a (List (List a))
```

Alas, Coq does not accept the type

```
Inductive  List4 : Type -> Type :=
  | Empty4: forall A, List4 A
  | Cons4 : forall A, A -> List4 (List4 A) -> List4 A
.
```

since the inner `List4` occurrence is not in a strictly positive position. This is probably a hint that I should stop being lazy and using Coq to do the work, and start thinking about the involved F-algebras by myself... ;-)