# Shortcut fusion for triemaps

Tags: haskell

This problem arose when attempting to fuse away intermediate triemaps in Haskell.

Consider the trie for Peano natural numbers:

```
data Nat = Zero | Succ Nat

data ExpoNat a = ExpoNat (Maybe a) (ExpoNat a)
               | NoExpoNat
```

We can easily define a fold on `ExpoNat` (it is essentially a list) and use [foldr/build](https://wiki.haskell.org/Correctness_of_short_cut_fusion#foldr.2Fbuild_2) (a.k.a. [finally tagless](http://okmij.org/ftp/tagless-final/index.html)) to fuse away intermediate occurrencess of `ExpoNat`:

```
{-# NOINLINE fold #-}
fold :: (Maybe a -> b -> b) -> b -> ExpoNat a -> b
fold f z (ExpoNat x y) = f x (fold f z y)
fold f z NoExpoNat = z

{-# NOINLINE build #-}
build :: (forall b. (Maybe a -> b -> b) -> b -> b) -> ExpoNat a
build f = f ExpoNat NoExpoNat

{-# RULES "fold/build" forall f n (g :: forall b. (Maybe a -> b -> b) -> b -> b). fold f n (build g) = g f n #-}
```

As an example, we take `match` and `appl` from "[Is there a way to generalize this TrieMap code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45204600/is-there-a-way-to-generalize-this-triemap-code)" and compose them such that `ExpoNat` is fused away. (Note that we must "strengthen the induction hypothesis" in `appl`.)

```
{-# INLINE match #-}
match :: Nat -> ExpoNat ()
match n = build $ \f z ->
  let go Zero = f (Just ()) z
      go (Succ n) = f Nothing (go n)
  in go n

{-# INLINE appl #-}
appl :: ExpoNat a -> (Nat -> Maybe a)
appl
  = fold (\f z -> \n ->
            case n of Zero    -> f
                      Succ n' -> z n')
         (\n -> Nothing)

applmatch :: Nat -> Nat -> Maybe ()
applmatch x = appl (match x)
```

The fusion can be verified by inspecting Core with `-ddump-simpl`.

Now we would like to do the same for `Tree`.

```
data Tree = Leaf | Node Tree Tree

data TreeMap a
  = TreeMap {
        tm_leaf :: Maybe a,
        tm_node :: TreeMap (TreeMap a)
    }
  | EmptyTreeMap
```

We are in trouble: `TreeMap` is a non-regular data type, and so it is not obvious how to write its corresponding fold/build pair.

[Haskell Programming with Nested Types: A Principled Approach](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/3cb7/d5c74497fc23d813de4d121c0796eb82962b.pdf) seems to have the answer (see the `Bush` type) but 4:30 AM seems to be too late for me to get it working.  How is one supposed to write `hfmap`?  Have there been further developments since?

A similar variant of this question has been asked in [What's the type of a catamorphism (fold) for non-regular recursive types?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30810090/whats-the-type-of-a-catamorphism-fold-for-non-regular-recursive-types)

Answer (score 3):

I worked on it some more and I now have working fusion, without using the generic gadgets from the paper.

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE TypeOperators #-}
{-# LANGUAGE KindSignatures #-}
{-# LANGUAGE PolyKinds #-}
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFunctor #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveFoldable #-}
{-# LANGUAGE DeriveTraversable #-}
module Tree where

data Tree = Leaf | Node Tree Tree
  deriving (Show)

data ExpoTree a = ExpoTree (Maybe a) (ExpoTree (ExpoTree a))
                | NoExpoTree
  deriving (Show, Functor)
```

I derived most of the specialized types by taking the generic construction and then inlining type definitions until I bottomed out.  I've kept the generic construction in here for ease of comparison.

```
data HExpoTree f a = HExpoTree (Maybe a) (f (f a))
                   | HNoExpoTree

type g ~> h = forall a. g a -> h a

class HFunctor f where
  ffmap :: Functor g => (a -> b) -> f g a -> f g b
  hfmap :: (Functor g, Functor h) => (g ~> h) -> (f g ~> f h)

instance HFunctor HExpoTree where
  ffmap f HNoExpoTree = HNoExpoTree
  ffmap f (HExpoTree x y) = HExpoTree (fmap f x) (fmap (fmap f) y)
  hfmap f HNoExpoTree = HNoExpoTree
  hfmap f (HExpoTree x y) = HExpoTree x (f (fmap f y))

type Alg f g = f g ~> g

newtype Mu f a = In { unIn :: f (Mu f) a }

instance HFunctor f => Functor (Mu f) where
  fmap f (In r) = In (ffmap f r)

hfold :: (HFunctor f, Functor g) => Alg f g -> (Mu f ~> g)
hfold m (In u) = m (hfmap (hfold m) u)
```

An `Alg ExpoTreeH g` can be decomposed into a product of two natural transformations:

```
type ExpoTreeAlg g = forall a. Maybe a -> g (g a) -> g a
type NoExpoTreeAlg g = forall a. g a

{-# NOINLINE fold #-}
fold :: Functor g => ExpoTreeAlg g -> NoExpoTreeAlg g -> ExpoTree a -> g a
fold f z NoExpoTree = z
fold f z (ExpoTree x y) = f x (fold f z (fmap (fold f z) y))
```

The natural transformation here `c ~> x` is very interesting, and turns out to be quite necessary.  Here's the build translation:

```
hbuild :: HFunctor f => (forall x. Alg f x -> (c ~> x)) -> (c ~> Mu f)
hbuild g = g In

newtype I :: (* -> *) where
  I :: x -> I x
  deriving (Show, Eq, Functor, Foldable, Traversable)

-- Needs to be a newtype, otherwise RULE firer gets bamboozled
newtype ExpoTreeBuilder c = ETP {runETP :: (forall x. Functor x
                                        => (forall a. Maybe a -> x (x a) -> x a)
                                        -> (forall a. x a)
                                        -> (forall a. c a -> x a)
                                            )}

{-# NOINLINE build #-}
build :: ExpoTreeBuilder c -> forall a. c a -> ExpoTree a
build g = runETP g ExpoTree NoExpoTree
```

The newtype for the builder function is needed, because GHC 8.0 doesn't know how to fire the RULE without.

Now, the shortcut fusion rule:

```
{-# RULES "ExpoTree fold/build"
          forall (g :: ExpoTreeBuilder c) c (f :: ExpoTreeAlg g) (n :: NoExpoTreeAlg g).
          fold f n (build g c) = runETP g f n c #-}
```

Implementation of 'match' with 'build':

```
{-# INLINE match #-}
match :: Tree -> ExpoTree ()
match n = build (match_mk n) (I ())
  where
    match_mk :: Tree -> ExpoTreeBuilder I
    match_mk Leaf = ETP $ \ f z (I c) -> f (Just c) z
    match_mk (Node x y) = ETP $ \ f z c ->
      -- NB: This fmap is bad for performance
      f Nothing (fmap (const (runETP (match_mk y) f z c)) (runETP (match_mk x) f z c))
```

Implementation of 'appl' with 'fold' (we need to define a custom functor to define the return type.)

```
newtype PFunTree a = PFunTree { runPFunTree :: Tree -> Maybe a }
  deriving (Functor)

{-# INLINE appl #-}
appl :: ExpoTree a -> PFunTree a
appl = fold appl_expoTree appl_noExpoTree
  where
    appl_expoTree :: ExpoTreeAlg PFunTree
    appl_expoTree = \z f -> PFunTree $ \n ->
                case n of Leaf       -> z
                          Node n1 n2 -> runPFunTree f n1 >>= flip runPFunTree n2
    appl_noExpoTree :: NoExpoTreeAlg PFunTree
    appl_noExpoTree = PFunTree $ \n -> Nothing
```

Putting it all together:

```
applmatch :: Tree -> Tree -> Maybe ()
applmatch x = runPFunTree (appl (match x))
```

We can once again inspect the core with `-ddump-simpl`. Unfortunately, while we have successfully fused away the `TrieMap` data structure, we are left with suboptimal code due to the `fmap` in `match`. Eliminating this inefficiency is left to future work.

Answer (score 2):

The paper appears to draw a parallel between `ExpoNat a` as a recursive `Type` and `Tree` as a recursive type constructor (`Type -> Type`).

```
newtype  Fix f   =  Fix (f ( Fix f))
newtype HFix h a = HFix (h (HFix h) a)
```

`Fix f` represents the least fixed point of the endofunctor on the category of types and functions, `f :: Type -> Type`; `HFix h` represents the least fixed point of the endofunctor `h` on a category of functors and natural transformations, `h :: (Type -> Type) -> (Type -> Type)`.

```
-- x ~ Fix (ExpoNatF a) ~ ExpoNat
data ExpoNatF a x = ExpoNatF (Maybe a) x | NoExpoNatF

fmap :: (x -> y) -> ExpoNatF a x -> ExpoNatF a y
fmap f (ExpoNatF u v) = ExpoNatF u (f v)
fmap _ NoExpoNatF = NoExpoNatF


-- f ~ HFix TreeMapH ~ TreeMap
data TreeMapH f a = TreeMapH (Maybe a) (f (f a)) | EmptyTreeMapH

hfmap :: (f ~> g) -> (TreeMapH f ~> TreeMapH g)
hfmap f (TreeMapH u v) = TreeMapH u ((fmap . fmap) f v)
hfmap _ EmptyTreeMapH = EmptyTreeMapH


-- (~>) is the type of natural transformations
type f ~> g = forall a. f a -> g a
```

- Endofunctors give rise to algebras.

  ```
  type  Alg f a = f a -> a
  type HAlg h f = h f ~> f
  ```
- `fold`, or `cata` maps any algebra to a morphism (function|natural transformation).

  ```
   cata ::  Alg f a ->   Fix f -> a
  hcata :: HAlg h f -> (HFix h ~> h)
  ```
- `build` constructs a value from its Church encoding.

  ```
  type  Church f = forall a.  Alg f a -> a
  type HChurch h = forall f. HAlg h f ~> f

   build ::  Church f ->  Fix f
  hbuild :: HChurch h -> HFix h a

  -- The paper actually has a slightly different type for Church encodings, derived from the categorical view, but I'm pretty sure they're equivalent
  ```
- `build/fold` fusion is summarized by one equation.

  ```
   cata alg ( build f) = f alg
  hcata alg (hbuild f) = f alg
  ```

Comment: More general for HFix we can use HBase (as alternative of high ordered version of Base of recursion schemes of Kmett)
https://gist.github.com/xgrommx/4c72ae9d407214deab55fe9aebc08b45